# Is K theory ever trivial because of the ring, and not because of the kinds of modules we look at?

Tags: ct.category-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Let $\mathcal C$ be some Waldhausen category; we know that the K-theory $K(\mathcal C)$ might be trivial if $\mathcal C$ contains objects that are too ``big'' in some sense---for instance, via the Eilenberg swindle.

(Example: An infinite-dimensional vector space is isomorphic to a direct sum of itself and a finite-dimensional vector space, so any finite-dimensional and any infinite-dimensional vector space have the same K-theory class; on the other hand, any infinite-dimensional vector space represents an idempotent element in the $K_0$ group, but the only idempotent in a group is the identity, so must represent zero.)

So I have two related questions:

(1) In known examples where the K-theory of $\mathcal C$ is trivial, does it tend to be because of Eilenberg-swindle-type reasons?

(1)(a) Specializing to the categories of sheaves on a variety, or on a non-commutative space, I understand that adjectives like quasi-coherent sheaves, or perfect sheaves, or coherent sheaves, or Ind-coherent sheaves, are important to distinguish how big the objects in our categories are. If you would be able to clarify the size or `infinite-dimensionality' of the objects in each such category, I would be very grateful! For instance, should I just always assume that the stable oo-category of Ind-coherent sheaves always has trivial K-theory?

(2) Are there examples of when the underlying `ring' is so big that the K-theory has to be trivial? For instance, if I have some non-compact space with gigantic $\pi_1$, is it true that if I looked at its based loop space and modules over the based loop space, its K-theory will be trivial? What if I only look at perfect modules over such an algebra? (Here, you can take singular chains to think about based loops as an algebra in chain complexes, or you can think of it as an $E_1$ ring spectrum. I am interested in either answer.)

Comment: For (1), see the notion of a phantom triangulated category, e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.6183 . These objects are small categories of geometric origin which nevertheless have vanishing K-theory.

Comment: For (2), group rings can never have trivial K-theory, as they contain the integers as a retract.

Comment: One antithetical notion to the situation in the Eilenberg swindle is stable finiteness, that is, in all matrix rings over $R$, right invertible elements are invertible (equivalently, no finitely generated free module on $k$ generators can be isomorphic to a proper direct summand of a free module on $k'$ generators if $k \geq k'$). And indeed, this property is equivalent to all nonzero finitely generated projectives having nonzero image in K${}_0$.

Comment: The leavitt algebra $L_2$ with generators $x,x’,y,y’$ and relations $x’x=1=y’y$, $x’y=0=y’x$ and $xx’+yy’=1$ is a finitely presented simple algebra with trivial $K_0$ over any field. I feel this is a little smaller than the Eilenberg swindle since the algebra is finitely presented.

Comment: Of course commutative algebras have nontrivial K-theory of finitely generated modules, by tensoring with a field.

Answer (score 10):

If $R\cong R\oplus R$ as an $R$-bimodule, then for any module $R$-module $N$, we have
$$N\cong N\otimes R\cong N\otimes (R\oplus R)\cong (N\otimes R)\oplus 
(N\otimes R)\cong N\oplus N$$
so that every $[N]$ is trivial in $K$-theory.

For a concrete example, let $S$ be any ring and $R$ the ring of column-finite countable-by-countable matrices over $S$.

Comment: You surely don't mean an infinite product of rings? If $S$ is commutative ("any ring"), then so is $R$ and thus the free module on one generator has nontrivial image in K${}_0(R)$. Presumably, you mean the endomorphism ring of the countably generated free module over $S$. Or do you mean that if $S$ has trivial K$_0$, then so does $R$?

Comment: @DavidHandelman:  Yes, my final sentence was of course absurd.  Thanks for catching it.  I'm fixing it.